# ScrollView Not Scrolling within SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, scrollview, slidingdrawer

I have an XML with a hierarchy like such:

```
|- Relative Layout
   |----> TextView
   |----> TextView
   |----> Gallery
   |----> Sliding Drawer
          |----> Button (handle for Sliding Drawer)
          |----> ScrollView
                 |----> LinearLayout
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
                 |----> TextView
```

But when I toggle the handle (to expand the SlidingDrawer), then attempt to scroll the ScrollView, it doesn't scroll despite the content being properly displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just an update: I've tried overriding the touch event listener, setting the SlidingDrawer's 'clickable' property, and just about every variation of other questions similar to mine (Although not exact). No matter what I do, the SlidingDrawer takes focus over the child ScrollView (evidenced by overriding the onTouchEventListener and spitting out stuff in logcat for both the SlidingDrawer AND ScrollView - ScrollView's listener is never called).

Comment: did you find a solution? i have exactly the same problem...

Comment: The handle wasn't properly set. My handle ('Button') was named something else than what the SlidingDrawer had listed as the ID for 'Handle'

Answer (score 3):

Check that `Scrollview` has the `id` "id/content" instead of the `LinearLayout`

Like this:

```
<ScrollView
  android:id="@id/content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Also make sure that `LinearLayout` has the correct `layout_width` and `layout_height` set